# Innodb_buffer_pool_reads ,Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests reset

Tags: mysql

Except from restart,when Innodb_buffer_pool_reads , Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests parameters reset to zero?

Comment: In reading your question again, I see that maybe I did not answer what you really asked.  I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you reset two specific status variables.

You can only reset all of them using [`FLUSH STATUS;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html#flush-status)

> This option adds the current thread's session status variable values to the global values and resets the session values to zero. ***Some global variables may be reset to zero as well. It also resets the counters for key caches (default and named)*** to zero and sets Max_used_connections to the current number of open connections. This information may be of use when debugging a query. See Section 1.7, “How to Report Bugs or Problems”.

Try running [`FLUSH STATUS;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html#flush-status) and see if this works.

Comment: For FLUSH STATUS; and  Some global variables may be reset to zero as well. It also resets the counters for key caches (default and named) .+1

Answer (score 1):

"Global" things have only "global" values; `FLUSH STATUS` has no effect on many of them.  The "buffer pool" is a global thing; there are no "session" values, only "global" values.

Not many things are reset by `FLUSH STATUS`.  This is an approximately complete list:

```
Aborted_%
Key_%  (MyISAM)
Subquery_cache_%  (MariaDB)
Table_locks_waited
```

If your question is about big counters overflowing, then the answer is "yes, but".  If MySQL is built as a 32-bit version, most (all?) `STATUS` values are limited to what can fit in 32 bits.  They will roll over and "reset to zero", then continue counting up.  With a 64-bit build, there is probably nothing that will roll over in your lifetime.

In particular, the two `Innodb_%` things you mentioned will roll over in a 32-bit build, but have plenty of room to continue to grow in a 64-bit build.